# Question about lemma (2) - Spivak' calculus - page 89

Tags: calculus

I have a question about the proof of lemma (2) in Spivak's calculus, page 89. How does he simplifies
$$
\ |y_0|\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}
$$
to get
$$
\ \frac{\epsilon}2
$$
Thanks.

Comment: He doesn't simplify, he estimates, using $\frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{\lvert y_0\rvert + 1} < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any $x$,

$|x| < |x| + 1 \implies \frac{|x|}{|x| + 1} < 1$